# Java 8 Stream: 1 Object to 2 Objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to do something like this with the Stream API?

```
 LinkedList<Point> l = new LinkedList<>();
        for(Edge e : EDGES){
            l.add(e.p1);
            l.add(e.p2);
        }
```

I want to get Point A and Point B from 3 Edges of a Triangle and eliminate the duplicates with .distinct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a Stream of all the `Point`s of all the edges using `flatMap` and remove the duplicates with `distinct()` :

```
LinkedList<Point> l =
    EDGES.stream()
         .flatMap(e->Stream.of(e.p1,e.p2))
         .distinct()
         .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new);
```

Comment: Just to emphasize: there is no reason to use `LinkedList` here…

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
List<Point> l = EDGES.stream().flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e.p1, e.p2)).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or by using a `Set`

```
Set<Point> l = EDGES.stream().flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e.p1, e.p2)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```